# Add text to Y-Axis

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to build a chart using PHPExcel where the Y-axis labels are text (see screenshot). Any suggestions?

I've tried [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/137528/en-us) but it only works for 2 values (min, max), I need more labels as shown in the screenshot.

The screenshot comes from a [question I posted](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/add-text-to-y-axis/fa4ea48c-a541-44c9-923c-37eed5278b6e) on the Microsoft Forums, but their solution doesn't work in my case.

[image: chart example]

Comment: Yep, this is the better forum for your question.

Comment: Thanks teylyn, I'm surprised you found me here :) Yes, I've been researching this for quite some time now and no luck so far.